# Inverse of a function $B_r(0) \to \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inverse-function

> **Definition.** Let $B_r(0) := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \|x\| < r\}$ be the open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with radius $r>0$ and center $0:=(0,\ldots,0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $s_r : B_r(0) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be the map, defined by $$s_r(x) = \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-\|x\|^2}} \cdot x $$

Does this function have an inverse? If so, how does $s_r^{-1} : \mathbb{R}^n \to B_r(0)$ look like?

Comment: I suppose surjectivity is obvious, since $\|x\|$ can be made arbitrarily close to zero (and to $r$), since $B_r(0)$ is open.

Comment: You can try checking injectivity by looking at the individual entries in the vector. I think that the function is continuous. Also, write the proof of subjectivity rigorously. That will give you the inverse of your function.

Comment: You can try to solve for $x$ the equation $s_r(x) = y$ looking first at what norm should $x$ have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for injectivity, let $x,y \in B_r$ with $s_r(x)=s_r(y)$. Then, it follows that
$$
        \begin{alignat*}{3}
            && s_r(x) &= s_r(y) \\
            &\iff& \frac{rx}{\sqrt{r^2-\|x\|^2}} &= \frac{ry}{\sqrt{r^2-\|y\|^2}} \\
            &\iff& \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2-\|x\|^2}}}_{\text{scalar}} \underbrace{x}_{\text{vector}} &= \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2-\|y\|^2}}}_{\text{scalar}} \underbrace{y}_{\text{vector}}
        \end{alignat*}
$$
Since vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equal iff all components are equal, it suffices to prove that the scalar factors are the same:
$$
        \begin{alignat*}{3}
            &\iff& \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2-\|x\|^2}} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2-\|y\|^2}} \\
            &\iff& \frac{1}{r^2-\|x\|^2} &= \frac{1}{r^2-\|y\|^2} \\
            &\iff& r^2-\|x\|^2 &= r^2-\|y\|^2 \\
            &\iff& \|x\|^2 &= \|y\|^2 \\
            &\iff& \|x\| &= \|y\|
        \end{alignat*}
$$
This should prove the injectivity of $s_r$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=s_r(x)$. Take norm on both sides and solve the equation for $\|x\|$  to get $\|x\|=\frac {r\|y\|} {\sqrt {r^{2}+|\|y\|^{2}}}$. Can you write down $x$ in terms of $y$ now?

Comment: I can set $s_r^{-1}(x):= \frac{rx}{\sqrt{r^2 + \|x\|^2}}$. Left-inverse has worked, I will now tend to proving right-inverse as well. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!